# AmChart only works with more than 1 dataset

Tags: amcharts

I'm creating a stock chart using amchart, problem is if i only have 1 dataset for some reason it does not show any of the charts?

My chart works fine as long as i have more than 1 dataset returned from my server. with 1 dataset it just shows the 'time' bar at the bottom.

```
var firstRun = false;
                for(let item in data){                                       
                      console.log(data[item]); 

                    this.AmCharts.updateChart(this.chart, () => {
                        this.chart.dataSets.push({
                            "title": item,
                            "fieldMappings": [ {
                              "fromField": "value",
                              "toField": "value"
                            }, {
                              "fromField": "volume",
                              "toField": "volume"
                            } ],
                            "dataProvider": data[item],
                            "categoryField": "date",
                            "compared": firstRun
                          } );
                      });
                      firstRun = true;                     
                }
```

And I'm positive my chart data works as i got a button that loads the data, and if i press it twice with 1 set of data it will show correctly.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle/codepen/plunker that reproduces the problem.

Comment: This fiddle reproduce the problem http://jsfiddle.net/9e400ejs/8/ and the problem is that i have put "position": "top" if i change it to "left" it works.. but i dont want it at position left because there is no room for that at mobiles..

Comment: Think i will go with completly removing the "dataSetSelector": {
              "position": "left"
            }, then it will work without comparing.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle! Looks like you stumbled onto a bug. I'll file this in our tracker for the team to investigate.